# What is the equivalent of a call to drupal_http_request()?

Tags: 8

In Drupal 7 I am using the following code.

```
$url = 'testdomain/url';
$response = drupal_http_request($url, array('method' => 'POST', 'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8')));
if ($response->code == "200") {
  $result = $response->data;
}
```

What is the equivalent code I should use on Drupal 8?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Finally i find a code in https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21install.core.inc/8 (1375)

and its working for me :)

```
 try {
    $response = \Drupal::httpClient()->get($uri, array('headers' => array('Accept' => 'text/plain')));
    $data = (string) $response->getBody();
    if (empty($data)) {
      return FALSE;
    }
  }
  catch (RequestException $e) {
    return FALSE;
  }
```

Hope this will help for some one

Comment: No surprise, but this works for Drupal 9 as well.

Answer (score 2):

[HTTP client library added to replace drupal_http_request()](https://www.drupal.org/node/1862446)

```
$client = \Drupal::httpClient();
$request = $client->createRequest('GET', $feed->url);
$request->addHeader('If-Modified-Since', gmdate(DATE_RFC1123, $last_fetched));

try {
  $response = $client->get($feed->uri, [
    'headers' => [
      'If-Modified-Since' => gmdate(DATE_RFC1123, $last_fetched),
    ],
  ]);
  // Expected result.
  // getBody() returns an instance of Psr\Http\Message\StreamInterface.
  // @see http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/psr7.html#body
  $data = $response->getBody();
}
catch (RequestException $e) {
  watchdog_exception('my_module', $e);
}
```

Comment: Not Working :( "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.)

Watchdog error is : 

Recoverable fatal error: Argument 3 passed to GuzzleHttp\Client::request() must be of the type array, string given, called in /var/www/drupal8/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php on line 87 and defined in GuzzleHttp\Client->request() (line 126 of /var/www/drupal8/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php)

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/1862446#comment-10640294

Comment: They fixed it, but yeah, change records are the first place to check :)

Comment: The code above uses $last_fetched var which is not defined anywhere and also in one place uses $feed->url and in onther $feed->uri

Comment: The error comes up as the RequestException class is not defined. Add use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me, sending a XML file with \Drupal::httpClient() POST

```
$endpoint  = 'http://example.com/something';
$xml = '<>'; // You're XML here.

// Make the request.
$options = [
  'connect_timeout' => 30,
  'debug' => true,
  'headers' => array(
    'Content-Type' => 'text/xml',
  ),
  'body' => $xml,
  'verify'=>true,
];

try {
  $client = \Drupal::httpClient();
  $request = $client->request('POST',$endpoint,$options);

}
catch (RequestException $e){
  // Log the error.
  watchdog_exception('custom_modulename', $e);
}

$responseStatus = $request->getStatusCode();
$responseXml = $request->getBody()->getContents();
```

Hope this helps.

More info about Guzzle here: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/index.html